# calling fragment from another fragment on button click

Tags: android-fragments

```
public class MasterDetailFragment extends Fragment {
    public interface onButtonItemSelected {
        public void onButtonItemSelected(int id);
    }
    onButtonItemSelected mListner;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Defines the xml file for the fragment
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.masterdetail_fragment, container, false);
        // Setup handles to view objects here
        // etFoo = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.etFoo);
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        Button _fragment0=(Button) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.button1);
        Button  _fragment1=(Button) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.button2);
        Button  _fragment2=(Button) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.button3);


        mListner=(onButtonItemSelected) getContext();
        _fragment1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                int id = v.getId();
                System.out.println(" ************ GENERATED ID IS : " + id);

                if( id==R.id.fragment1) {
                    FragmentTransaction fragTransaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                    fragTransaction.replace(R.id.masterdetail_fragment,new MovieDetailFragment() );
                    fragTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
                    fragTransaction.commit();
                    System.out.println(" ************ button1 " + id);
                }

            }
        });
        _fragment0.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                int id = v.getId();
                System.out.println(" ************ GENERATED ID IS : " + id);

                if( id==R.id.fragment0) {
                    mListner.onButtonItemSelected(R.id.myname);
                    System.out.println(" ************ button2 : " + id);
                }

            }
        });



    }
}
```

I am trying load movieDetail fragment from masterDetail fragment in a button click event.
I am not able to add new instance of movieDetail fragment as it throws the following compile time error. What should I do to be able to add new instance of the movie details fragment.

[image]

Comment: **MovieDetailFragment**  should extend from **fragment**

Comment: if you extend , please share some piece of code of **MovieDetailFragment**

Answer (score 0):

When you want to go to another **fragment** from **current fragment** class you should use

```
getChildFragmentManager()
```

instead of

```
getFragmentManager()
```

That's solve your problem.

Comment: @askatral can you put xml of **MasterDetails** and java code ** MovieDetails**